# Tkinter, updating label and using after

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

In the following code, I can scan a UPC code with a USB barcode scanner and take that 12 digit numeric string and do a search on it with a BASH script (called bss) that goes out to the Internet, using, Lynx, and find that product and strip all the UN-needed text down to the description.

The problem is that there seems to be a limitation on how many times a label can be updated. In the function called `def get_key(self, event)` I can get the label to update twice. The displaying of the UPC code in the status frame and the resetting of the label back to "Ready...". Any more updates to that label only results in the displaying of the last one defined. It neverminds all between.

Why? In the second function `def get_info(self)`, I can only get it to update once. That is to the product information, and that remains until I scan again and then updates to the new item scanned, which is fine, but not the desired results, which is the changing of the lable back to "Waiting...". Any information or guidance would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess

class ShopApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        frameCenter = Frame(self)
        frameCenter.configure(height=50, width=300, background='#dddbe3')
        frameCenter.propagate(0) 
        frameCenter.pack(side=TOP)

        frameStatus = Frame(self, padx=2, pady=2)
        frameStatus.configure(height=30, width=300) 
        frameStatus.propagate(0)    
        frameStatus.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.mdItemAdded = tk.Label(frameCenter, text="Waiting...")
        self.mdItemAdded.config(font=('sans', 12, 'bold'))
        self.mdItemAdded.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        self.code = ' '     
        self.status = tk.Label(frameStatus, text="Ready...")
        self.status.config(height=20, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        self.status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        self.bind('<Key>', self.get_key)

    #Getting Barcode scan
    def get_key(self, event):
        if event.char in '0123456789':
            self.code += event.char     
            self.status['text'] = "UPC Code: " + self.code     

        elif self.status == self.status:
            self.status.after(3000)     
            self.status['text'] = "Ready..."
            self.get_info()
            self.code = ' '

    #Displaying Results
    def get_info(self):
    result = subprocess.call('/home/pi/python/shop/bss ' + (self.code), shell=True)
        if result == 0:
            self.f = open ('final.txt',  'r')
            self.line = self.f.readline()
            self.f.close()
            self.mdItemAdded.config(text="Item Added...\n" + self.line)
            self.mdItemAdded.update_idletasks()
            self.mdItemAdded.after(4000)
            self.mdItemAdded.config(text="Waiting...")


shopper = ShopApp()
shopper.mainloop()
```

Comment: some of your indentation is incorrect. Also, can you please write an example program that does not require us to run some specialized script that is not included in the question?

Comment: FWIW, there absolutely is no limit to how many times you can change a label.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to add `self.mdItemAdded.update_idletasks()` to the bottom of `def get_info(self)` function. I updated my code to reflect the working changes.

Comment: If you modify the code in the question so that it works, it will confuse everyone who reads this question. Either put the solution in an answer, or delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my question to reflect the corrections in the code that has ultimately solved my issue.

The fix is:

```
self.mdItemAdded.update_idletasks()
self.mdItemAdded.after(4000)
self.mdItemAdded.config(text="Waiting...")
```

added to the end of the `def_get_info(self)` function. I hope this helps anyone that might run across the same issue.